# ajax:succuess not called when submit a form remotly rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

Basically, I want to submit a create new course form and handle the response using JQuery.
My form like

```
<div id="create_coursem">
  <%= form_tag({:controller => "coursem", :action => "create"}, :id => "check_coursem_form", :method => "post", :remote => true) do %>
      <p>
      <b> <%= label_tag(:name, "Name:") %> </b>
      <%= text_field_tag(:name) %>
      </p>
      <p>
      <b> <%= label_tag(:department, "Department:") %> </b>
      <%= select_tag "department", @result.html_safe %>
      </p>
      <%= submit_tag("Create") %>

  <% end %>

</div>
```

And in my controller, I have

```
  def create
    @coursem = Coursem.createCoursemByUser(params[:name], params[:department])
    @errCode = @coursem
    if @coursem.class != Fixnum
      @errCode = 1
    end
    @dic = {:errCode => @errCode, :coursem => @coursem}
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render json: @dic}
    end
  end
```

The response status is 200, so it means that it successfully return a json. And in my JS file, I have

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    panelHandler();
    //showOverview();
    showResources();
    resourceHandler();
    calendarChangeMonth();
    subscribeHandler();

    shownewresourceform();

    eventinfo();
    closeeventbox();
    showneweventform();
    colorrecentevents();
    check_coursem();
})
    function check_coursem() {
        $("form#check_coursem_form").on('ajax:beforeSend', function(xhr, settings) {alert("hello");})
                                .on('ajax:success',    function(data, status, xhr) {alert("hello");})
                                .on('ajax:complete', function(xhr, status) {alert("hello");})
                                .on('ajax:error', function(xhr, status, error) {alert("hello");});
    }
```

But when I click the create button, it only return the json generated by the create controller, no alert is shown. Anyone know the reason why?
Really appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it tries to parse the response as a javascript response, rather than a json response.

Try this:

```
form_tag({:controller => "coursem", :action => "create"}, :id => "check_coursem_form", :method => "post", :remote => true, :data => { :type => 'json' }) do %>
```

Answer (score -1):

I haven't worked a ton with ajax, but I've never seen a request formatted like that...
Have you tried implementing something more like in the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)?

```
// Assign handlers immediately after making the request,
// and remember the jqxhr object for this request
var jqxhr = $.ajax( "example.php" )
    .done(function() { alert("success"); })
    .fail(function() { alert("error"); })
    .always(function() { alert("complete"); });

// perform other work here ...

// Set another completion function for the request above
jqxhr.always(function() { alert("second complete"); });
```